# Foreign keys become untrusted after bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, sql-server-2014, bulk-insert

In a SQL 2014 edition server (12.0.2430.0 - no SP1 yet)
with a database in 2012 compatibility mode (working on getting it switched to 2014...) I have a handful of foreign key objects which are consistently marked as `not trusted` in the database. I've dropped and re-created them without `NOCHECK` options, but within 5-10 minutes they become untrusted again and if I generate a `CREATE` script it comes out as:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Points]  WITH NOCHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BadgeId] FOREIGN KEY([BadgeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Badge] ([Id])
GO
```

The create script being used is:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Points]
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BadgeId] FOREIGN KEY([BadgeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Badge] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Points] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BadgeId]
GO
```

There is no replication, there are no third party tools, and I am monitoring all DDL statements on the database so it isn't another user.

I am able to check the constraints fine (using `WITH CHECK CHECK` on each) but they still become untrusted shortly after. Only maintenance jobs that run are Ola's in the early AM and this happens throughout the day.

**Update:**

So, after a couple of traces to narrow down possibilities, it seems like a `BULK INSERT` may be causing the `FK` to become untrusted. [This msdn question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b6bb16c-06e7-40d4-9e2b-fba982a74b0b/sysforeignkeys-isnottrusted-problem?forum=sqldatabaseengine) states that this is a valid route for the key to become untrusted, which is the first I've heard of it.

So my question now is, is there an alternative strategy to using `BULK INSERT` that can maintain foreign key `is_trusted` status? It's being executed in the context of an application running several times per hour. I could have the developers batch their insert statements instead, but I'd prefer not to put an ultimatum on using `BULK INSERT` if I don't have to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `BULK INSERT` from our application was the cause of untrusted foreign keys, as confirmed by an [MSDN question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b6bb16c-06e7-40d4-9e2b-fba982a74b0b/sysforeignkeys-isnottrusted-problem?forum=sqldatabaseengine). Similar to `BCP`, anytime a `BULK INSERT` is performed then the foreign key is not checked during insert, therefor making it not trusted.

As Kin mentioned, there are [simple scripts](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Repair-Not-Trusted-FK-499a0bda) available to find and fix untrusted foreign keys, but in my scenario the inserts are happening at frequency which makes effort to constantly fix this issue not worth it.

And ypercube suggested using `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` [option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) within the bulk inserts which would force the constraint to be obeyed.

I plan to review with the developers to ensure that each usage of `BULK INSERT` is justified in terms of rows inserted, otherwise it will have to be something to live with.

Comment: I was using `SqlBulkCopy` with the same effect, but there is (at least now) an option to do the bulk copy while still checking the constraints - which means that the bulk copy facility can do checking in principal, most likely bcp has some option to enable that. Whoever made the non-checking mode the default needs to be punched in the face.